# How to update gitlab badges during CI without using personal access token

Tags: gitlab, badge

How to update gitlab badges during the CI without using a personal access token?

I have version badge and want to update it after every build. Therefore, I use maven to get the current version and update the badge using the API.

```
curl --silent --request PUT --header "Private-Token: $GITLAB_API_TOKEN" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/badges/1 -d image_url=https://img.shields.io/badge/version-${VERSION}-blue.svg
```

However, the GITLAB_API_TOKEN has to be a personal access token. Saving the GITLAB_API_TOKEN in the repository variables allows other developers to access the variable. Therefore, a developer can use another developers personal access key.

Is there another option to update gitlab project badges?

Update: there is a gitlab issue regarding this feature: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15666

Answer (score 1):

Check if you still have to do that update, or if [GitLab 14.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/02/22/gitlab-14-8-released/#latest-release-badge-for-the-project) (February 2022) does it for you

> ### Latest Release badge for the project
>
> We have added a new badge so you can easily see the version of your latest release right in the project page.
>
> Thank you [Jason D’Amour](https://gitlab.com/jason.damour) for your contribution!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_8/release-latest-release-badge.png -- Latest Release badge for the project]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#latest-release-badge) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/33368).